# store bits(byte) in long long by concatenation

Tags: c, arrays, byte, concatenation, long-integer

poly8_bitslice() array if `char` as input, this input will be converted to bits(byte) by the function `intToBits()`.

After the conversion I want to store the result in a `long long` variable. Is this possible?
Can I concatenate the result of `intToBits()`?

I want to do this with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned char poly8;
typedef unsigned long long poly8x64[8];

void intToBits(unsigned k, poly8 nk[8]) {
    int i; 
    for(i=7;i>=0;i--){        
        nk[i] = (k%2);        
        k = (int)(k/2);
    }
}

void poly8_bitslice(poly8x64 r, const poly8 x[64])
{
  //TODO
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<64;i++){
        poly8 xb[8];
        intToBits(x[i], xb);
        int j;
        long long row;
        for(j=0;j<8;j++){
            row = row + x[j];
        }

        printf("row=%d \n", row);         
    }
}

int main()
{

  poly8 a[64], b[64], r[64];
  poly8x64 va, vb, vt;
  int i;

  FILE *urandom = fopen("/dev/urandom","r");
  for(i=0;i<64;i++)
  {
    a[i] = fgetc(urandom);
    b[i] = fgetc(urandom);
  }

  poly8_bitslice(va, a);
  poly8_bitslice(vb, b);

  fclose(urandom);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `k = (int)(k/2);` why are you casting an unsigned to signed?

Comment: You should include `inttypes.h` and use all fixed-width types instead of making up your own.  Use uint8_t and unit64_t.

Comment: `long long row; ... printf("row=%d \n", row);` does not use a matching specifier.  Use `printf("row=%lld \n", row);` and enable all compiler warnings - which should have told you this.

Comment: Which type do you want? `long long` as in "I want to store the result in a long long variable" or `unsigned long long` as in `unsigned long long poly8x64[8];`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understood your question but you can do something like this

```
char ch0 = 0xAA;
char ch1 = 0xBB;
char ch2 = 0xCC;
char ch3 = 0xDD;
long long int x = 0;           // x is 0x00000000
x = (long long int)ch0;        // x is 0x000000AA
x = x << 8;                    // x is 0x0000AA00
x = x | (long long int)ch1;    // x is 0x0000AABB
x = x << 8;                    // x is 0x00AABB00
x = x | (long long int)ch2;    // x is 0x00AABBCC
x = x << 8;                    // x is 0xAABBCC00
x = x | (long long int)ch3;    // x is 0xAABBCCDD
```

In this case x would contain `0xAABBCCDD`

The `<<` operator will shift the content of the left hand operator by the number specified by the right hand operator. So `0xAA << 8` would become `0xAA00`. Note that it will append zeros at the end while shifting.
The`|` operator will perform a bitwise or on both its operands. That is a bit by bit or. So the first bit of the left hand operator will be or'ed with the first bit of the right hand operator and the result will be placed in the first bit of the result. 
Anything or'ed with zero results to its self so

```
0xAA00 | 0x00BB
```

would result in

```
0xAABB
```

In general a bit append function would be

```
long long int bitAppend(long long int x, char ch) {
    return ((x << 8) | (long long int)ch);
}
```

This function would take the long long integer that you need to append to and the char to append to it and would return the appended long long int. Note that as soon as the 64 bits are filled up the high order bits will be shifted out.

For example

```
long long int x = 0x1122334455667788
x = x << 8;    // x now is 0x2233445566778800
```

this would result into x being `0x2233445566778800` since there is only 64bits in a long long int so the high order bits had to move out.

Comment: Certainly the cast is not needed in `x = (long long int)ch0;`, etc.  Left shifting in the the sign bit is UB.